# Mongoose-Validator or custom validation?

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose, server-side-validation

What you think is the best, using the mongoose validation module at your models definition or make your own validation functions before trying to save some document?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own validator, or you can use a npm package and extend the validator package to mongoose.

You can use, for example, [mongules](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongules) to do your validations in mongoose.